# Excluding erroneous solutions of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following trigonometric equation, which needs to be solved for $\theta$:

$\tan{(\pi\cot{\theta})}=\cot{(\pi\tan{\theta})}$

The solution given is:
$\tan{\theta}=\dfrac{2n+1\pm\sqrt{4n^2+4n-15}}{4}$ for integral values of $n$, AND $n>1$ or $n<-2$.

The method I adopted to arrive at this solutions was to first write $\cot{(\pi\tan{\theta})}$ as $\tan{(\pi/2-\pi\tan{\theta})}$. Then I wrote the general expression for all angles whose tangent is same as $\tan{(\pi/2-\pi\tan{\theta})}$ and equated it to $\pi\cot{\theta}$ and then solved the resulting equation for $\tan{\theta}$. I was able to arrive at the above expression (including the crucial step of excluding those values of $n$ which made the answer imaginary). But my worry is that there is still a lot to be done!

We need to consider the following 4 steps of excluding those values of integral $n$ for which:

(i) $\tan{\theta}=0$ (as this leaves the RHS of the equation undefined)

(ii) $\tan{\theta}$ is undefined (as this leaves the argument in the RHS as undefined)

(iii) $\tan{\theta}$ is an integer (as this leaves the RHS of the equation undefined)

(iv) $\cot{\theta}$ or reciprocal of $\tan{\theta}$ is of the form $k+\frac{1}{2}$, where $k$ is an integer (as this leaves the LHS of the equation undefined)

Now case (i) and (ii) need not be considered, as they are never satisfied for any of the values of $n$ provided in the answer. But cases (iii) and (iv) need some attention. For example, if I put $n=2$, then the answer says $\tan{\theta}=2$ or $\tan{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}$. The former answer leaves the RHS (as well as the LHS in this case) undefined.

My question is **What are other similar erroneous values of 'n' which do not conform with the 4 cases considered and as a result, invalidate the given solution**? Or is there any other method by which I can arrive at a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

cases iii) and iv) both require $\tan\theta$ to be rational.

In wich case, $4n^2 + 4n - 15$ is a perfect square
$4n^2 + 4n - 15 = (2n+5)(2n-3)$ can only be a perfect square if both $(2n+5)(2n-3)$ are perfect squares.
The only perfect squares within $8$ units of each other that are both integers are $1,9.$

$n = 2, n=-3$ are problematic.

Comment: How can we say that $(2n+5)(2n-3)$ (which will be an odd number) can only be a perfect square if both $(2n+5)$ (odd number) and $(2n-3)$ (odd number) are perfect squares, as for example, 3*27=81, which is a perfect square (albeit both of them do not give the same value of $n$ in this case). What I am saying is that this statement is not enough to prove the assertion. It would be great if you could elaborate on that note.